# Crash report of matlab under the macOS sonoma

Tags: macos, matlab, crash

Recencly i updated my macbook into macOS sonoma. After the updating, every time when I open the matlab 2023a, a crash report will appear. I cannot figure out the reason why it happen and how to fix it. Can anyone could help to fix it?

the log of crash report is follows:

```
MATLAB Log File: /Users/.../matlab_crash_dump.6349-1

------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Log File
------------------------------------------------ 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Segmentation violation detected at 2023-09-15 16:49:53 +0800
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding           : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode               : continue (default)
  Default Encoding         : UTF-8
  Deployed                 : false
  Graphics Driver          : Uninitialized hardware 
  Java Version             : Java 1.8.0_202-b08 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  MATLAB Architecture      : maci64
  MATLAB Entitlement ID    : 6257193
  MATLAB Root              : /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app
  MATLAB Version           : 9.14.0.2337262 (R2023a) Update 5
  OpenGL                   : hardware
  Operating System         : Mac OS 版本14.0（版号23A339）
  Process ID               : 6349
  Processor ID             : x86 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 0, GenuineIntel
  Session Key              : 229023a8-3478-4f39-99fe-57e69f921273
  Window System            : Quartz

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Current Thread: '' id 0x317b3b000

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = c4de286423860001  RBX = 00007ffb5962ab80
  RCX = 0000000000000002  RDX = 0000000000000000
  RSP = 0000000317b37970  RBP = 0000000317b37970
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 0000000000000012

   R8 = 0000000000000000   R9 = 000060002b8c1100
  R10 = 0000000317b37360  R11 = 00007ff85ad06c40
  R12 = 0000000000000000  R13 = 0000000000000000
  R14 = 0000000000000000  R15 = 0000000000000000

  RIP = 00007ff817a21290  RFL = 0000000000000246

   CS = 000000000000002b   FS = 0000000000000000   GS = 0000000000000000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x000000010b6b3f34 /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/libmwfl.dylib+00007988 _ZN10foundation4core4diag15stacktrace_base7captureERKNS1_14thread_contextEm+00000052
[  1] 0x000000010b6b6f2a /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/libmwfl.dylib+00020266 _ZN10foundation4core4test17terminate_handledERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE+00002234
[  2] 0x000000010b6b6410 /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/libmwfl.dylib+00017424 _ZN10foundation4core4diag13terminate_logEPKcPK17__darwin_ucontext+00000128
[  3] 0x0000000118f96c1c /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00535580 _Z19mnPrintErrorMessageRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE+00011596
[  4] 0x0000000118f94ca3 /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00527523 _Z19mnPrintErrorMessageRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE+00003539
[  5] 0x0000000118f92655 /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00517717 mnFatalSignalHandler+00000149
[  6] 0x00007ff8178aa37d           /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib+00013181 _sigtramp+00000029
[  7] 0x0000000000600701                                   <unknown-module>+00000000
[  8] 0x00007ff8178e2d68 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation+00028008 CFDictionaryGetValue+00000046
[  9] 0x00007ffb2a9dcfb2 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IO80211.framework/Versions/A/IO80211+00016306 Apple80211Scan+00000654
[ 10] 0x000000014721de9f /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/matlab_startup_plugins/lmgrimpl/libmwlmgrimpl.dylib+02248351 AjEdeqBE+00001958
[ 11] 0x000000014722e0b9 /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/matlab_startup_plugins/lmgrimpl/libmwlmgrimpl.dylib+02314425 DWTmTEFs+00000215
[ 12] 0x000000014722d760 /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/matlab_startup_plugins/lmgrimpl/libmwlmgrimpl.dylib+02312032 nwlqjWBX+00000665
[ 13] 0x000000014722d5ff /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/matlab_startup_plugins/lmgrimpl/libmwlmgrimpl.dylib+02311679 nwlqjWBX+00000312
[ 14] 0x000000014722d925 /Applications/MATLAB_R2023a.app/bin/maci64/matlab_startup_plugins/lmgrimpl/libmwlmgrimpl.dylib+02312485 jfuBCSBK+00000045
[ 15] 0x00007ff81787d202            /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib+00025090 _pthread_start+00000099
[ 16] 0x00007ff817878bab            /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib+00007083 thread_start+00000015
```

I did nothing because i don't know the reason and the location of this crash.

Comment: Raise this with MathWorks support, you're paying for their software, they will help with installation issues

Comment: There will likely be a patch soon, if it’s not there yet. Check to see if there’s one ready! https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/check-for-software-updates.html

Comment: “Native Apple silicon MATLAB R2023b is supported on macOS Ventura (13) and macOS Monterey (12.6). macOS Sonoma Preview (14) is not currently supported.” https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/apple-silicon.html —— Sonoma is not supported even in R2023b: https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/matlab-mac.html —— I would recommend undoing the upgrade and wait for all the programs you use to support the new OS.

Comment: I have the same issue, on both M2 Macbook Air'15 and i7 Mac Mini (2018).

Answer (score 3):

When you installed MATLAB R2023b for Apple silicon, it may have inherited Java settings from a previous release that are not compatible with native MATLAB for Apple silicon. Amazon Corretto Java 8 is the only officially supported JRE for MATLAB on Apple silicon. For further information, you can check the following link:

https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/answers/2034929-why-does-matlab-r2023b-crash-on-my-apple-silicon-mac-after-installing-a-java-8-jre